# Question about audio recording my in-person conversations in New York

Tags: new-york-state, minor, recording, consent

In NY State, which is a 1 party consent state, can I audio record a conversation with my friend without their consent if they are a minor? ( I'm 18, he's 17 )

I was told minors can't consent to being audio recorded without parental consent, but if I only need my consent to record a conversation with an adult, why would they need consent from an adult?

I don't see anything regarding minors in https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/PEN/P3TNA250

I'm so confused. I'm not trying to blackmail anyone, I just like recording conversations with my friends so I can reference stuff I might forget about and or listen to the conversations in the future for nostalgia's sake.

Thanks.